# ECMAScript 2017, 5 Notational Conventions: What are productions, terminal and nonterminal symbols?

Tags: terminology, context-free-grammar

I have recently been diving into the ECMAScript specification (v. 2017). To understand the various parts, it is key to fully grasp section 5, `Notational Conventions`.

**Questions**

1. What are `productions`?
2. What are `nonterminal symbols`?
3. What are `terminal symbols`?

The first mention of these concepts are in "5.1.1 Context-Free Grammars":

> A context-free grammar consists of a number of productions. Each
>   production has an abstract symbol called a nonterminal as its
>   left-hand side, and a sequence of zero or more nonterminal and
>   terminal symbols as its right-hand side. For each grammar, the
>   terminal symbols are drawn from a specified alphabet.

Yet, I could not find an explanation of what is meant by the term `production`. Similarly, I was not able to figure out what `terminal` and `nonterminal` symbols are, and what the difference between the two is.

Comment: Terminal and nonterminal symbols are used in grammars, automatons and compilers theory to describe certain 'things'. If you really want to understand those, I would start there as explaining it here would take a really huge effort.

Comment: [Wikipedia: Context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). This is not specific to any of the tags you originally had, but this is about the [tag:terminology] of [tag:context-free-grammar]s.